# Magento 2 Product attributes

Tags: magento, magento2

I've created product drop-down attribute 'Types' for my project. But I want different values of that attribute for different products. For example:
Let's say a product can be of type a) Fruits or b) Vegetables
So for the product Fruits only options/values like Mango, Banana etc. should be visible and not the ones associated with vegetables.

How to achieve this?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because Stack Overflow is a [programming-related](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) Q&A site. Your question is not about programming. Perhaps you should post it on http://magento.stackexchange.com instead?